# Conditional formatting based on a rule

Tags: conditional-formatting

I am building a guest list for my wedding. I have 13 columns and 94 rows currently. I am looking for a conditional formatting formula to highlight the entire row if the cell in column `I` is blank. I have only been able to find a formula for when ANY cell is blank throughout the entire file. I've included a picture for reference:

[image: Guest Addresses]

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: What software is the question about? Please [edit] and add a proper tag at least.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your table/list, go to Conditional Formatting and create a new rule.
2. Select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.
3. Under `Format values where this formula is true` type `=COUNTIF($I2,"")>0`
4. Select the color to highlight and done.